# Why is $\limsup \sqrt[k]{\vert a_k \vert} = \limsup \sqrt[k]{\vert a_{k + 1} \vert}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I think I've read the fact somewhere that $\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{\vert a_k \vert} = \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{\vert a_{k + 1} \vert}$. However, I can't quite recall the proof.

Can someone help me one this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your series is convergent, I remember a theorem saying that, when you are far enough in your series' terms, since you are converging, you can say something like $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{\vert a_k \vert} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[k]{\vert a_{k + 1} \vert}$.

Comment: I may be missing something... What about $(a_k)_k)$ defined by $a_{2k} = \frac{1}{2^k}$ and $a_{2k+1} = \frac{1}{3^k}$?

Comment: I changed it to the limsup now. I think this might be true now...

Comment: Can I assume $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{a_k} > 0$?

Comment: Sure. I mean, I'm not quite sure about the fact anymore, I just want to find out what works :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} > 0$:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k+1]{|a_{k+1}|} \\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} |a_{k+1}|^{\frac 1{k+1}} \\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} |a_{k+1}|^{\frac 1k} \cdot |a_{k+1}|^{\frac 1{k+1}-\frac 1k} \\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} |a_{k+1}|^{\frac 1k} \cdot |a_{k+1}|^{-\frac 1{(k+1)k}} \\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} |a_{k+1}|^{\frac 1k} \cdot \frac1{\sqrt[k]{\sqrt[k+1]{|a_{k+1}|}}} \\
\end{align}$$

Because $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k+1]{|a_{k+1}|} = \lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{|a_k|} > 0$ we find $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\sqrt[k+1]{|a_{k+1}|}} = 1$ which proves $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}=\lim_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{|a_{k+1}|}$